# mod_rewrite QUERY_STRING value to new URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've tried so many ways to do this for days now and STILL somehow gotten nowhere. Making me crazy.  Seems like it ought to be relatively easy....
I need to rewrite traffic from an old app to a new one, but the format of the values passed is different.
This:
`http://oldapp.com/download.aspx?filename=FILE-01.pdf`
has to rewrite to this:
`https://NEWapp.com/this/that/FILE-01.pdf`

So I have to pull the value out of the QUERY_STRING, which in this example is `FILE-01.pdf`, and incorporate it into the new URL. There is always only one name/value pair in QUERY_STRING and it is always "download.aspx?filename=".

Seems really straightforward, right?  But I keep missing it. I have tried many, many variations of this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} filename=([\S\s]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://NEWapp.com/this/that/$1 [R,L]
```

I'm working with IBM HTTP Server v8.0, which is basically Apache 2.2.

**SOLUTION:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filename=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://NEWapp.com/this/that/%1? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} filename=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^download.aspx$ https://NEWapp.com/this/that/%1 [R,L]
```

When you access a capture group from a `RewriteCond` you need to use the backreference operator `%` rather than the `$` prefix which would be used for capture groups in a `RewriteRule`

Comment: Ack!  backreference!  I missed that, but...  still failing.  But at least I get a different error now.  Strangely, it doesn't rewrite to the new URL at all and instead 404's on the old one.  Instead of `https://newapp.com/ext/NEW-3.pdf` I 404 on `http://oldapp.com/download.aspx?filename=NEW-3.pdf`.

Comment: Got a `RewriteLogLevel 2` on this as well.  It reports:  `Debug log:  
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /download.aspx
(1) pass through /download.aspx
`

Comment: Perhaps try `RewriteRule ^/download.aspx$ ...` The forward slash is important if this is defined at a `VirtualHost` level and not in a `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

Following arco444 I would add a question mark at the end to make sure the query string doesn't go to the end of the url as well.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filename=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^download.aspx https://NEWapp.com/this/that/%1? [R,L]
```

If you would not add the question mark the final url will be `https://NEWapp.com/this/that/FILENAME.ext?filename=FILENAME.ext`

Comment: Thanks Dekel, that makes sense.  But I've still got something breaking before I reach that point.  I'll keep that question mark in mind as I experiment further.

Comment: This really should be a comment on my answer rather than an entire copy for the sake of a minor amendment. FWIW I deliberately didn't include the removal of the query string because I have no idea where the request goes after Apache and whether or not it could be discarded.

Comment: @arco444, by the time I posted the answer I wasn't able to comment on your answer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

It really seems like arco444's excellent answer should have done this, but, this is what finally works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filename=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://NEWapp.com/this/that/%1? [R,L]
```

I don't understand why this works and a specific match on download.aspx doesn't, but I am glad to have a solution.
Much gratitude to arco444 and Dekel.

Comment: If you found an answer helped you, you should really [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) rather than posting your own. In this case my answer didn't give you the exact answer by seems to have allowed you to solve the problem so I'll leave it up to you whether you choose to do that or not.